# Как рестартануть контейнер с обновленным образом?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

В файле `docker-compose.yml` есть следующая запись:

```
...
mkvworker:
    image: название образа в нашем регистре (какого-то специфичного)
    // какого-то специфичного тэга у образа нет, но образ был перезалит
...
```

Кроме данного сервиса запущено еще некоторое количество других сервисов, которые не следует останавливать.

Как можно рестартануть mkvworker, не останавливая другие сервисы, чтобы образ использовался не из кэша а спулился актуальный?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Попробуйте что то типа `docker-composer build --no-cache mkvworker` , а затем `docker-compose resart mkvworker` . Может сработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала явным образом pull'ишь образ для сервиса командой

```
docker-compose pull mkvworker
```

Если не указавать сервис (`mkvworker`), то он подтянет обновленные версии образов для всех сервисов из данного `docker-compose.yml`.
После перезапускашь

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps mkvworker
```

Теперь небольшая выдержка из документации

```
$ docker-compose up --help
Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.

The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When
the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d`
starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.

If there are existing containers for a service, and the service's configuration
or image was changed after the container's creation, `docker-compose up` picks
up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted
volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate`
flag.

If you want to force Compose to stop and recreate all containers, use the
`--force-recreate` flag.

Usage: up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                               print new container names. Incompatible with
                               --abort-on-container-exit.
    --no-color                 Produce monochrome output.
    --quiet-pull               Pull without printing progress information
    --no-deps                  Don't start linked services.
    --force-recreate           Recreate containers even if their configuration
                               and image haven't changed.
    --always-recreate-deps     Recreate dependent containers.
                               Incompatible with --no-recreate.
    --no-recreate              If containers already exist, don't recreate
                               them. Incompatible with --force-recreate and -V.
    --no-build                 Don't build an image, even if it's missing.
    --no-start                 Don't start the services after creating them.
    --build                    Build images before starting containers.
    --abort-on-container-exit  Stops all containers if any container was
                               stopped. Incompatible with -d.
    --attach-dependencies      Attach to dependent containers
    -t, --timeout TIMEOUT      Use this timeout in seconds for container
                               shutdown when attached or when containers are
                               already running. (default: 10)
    -V, --renew-anon-volumes   Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving
                               data from the previous containers.
    --remove-orphans           Remove containers for services not defined
                               in the Compose file.
    --exit-code-from SERVICE   Return the exit code of the selected service
                               container. Implies --abort-on-container-exit.
    --scale SERVICE=NUM        Scale SERVICE to NUM instances. Overrides the
                               `scale` setting in the Compose file if present.
```

Тут нас интересует секция:

> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service's configuration
> or image was changed after the container's creation, `docker-compose up` picks
> up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted
> volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate`
> flag.

По-русски говоря `up` пересоздаст контейнер из более-свежего образа, если таковой имеется, и не указана опция `--no-recreate`, которая отключает описанное пересоздание.

P.S. У образа всегда есть тэг, но если он не указан явно, то считается равным `latest`.

Comment: Круто! Работает)) и сильно быстрее моего костыльного способа. спасибо!